# How to realize the group by in rdd in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

```
data = sc.parallelize([('a','b','c', 1,4), ('o','u','w', 9,3), ('s','q','a', 8,6), ('l','g','z', 8,3), \
                       ('a','b','c', 9,8), ('s','q','a', 10,10), ('l','g','z', 20,20), ('o','u','w', 77,77)])
```

I have a rdd like this one. And I want to group the first three columns(like 'a','b','c') as keys, to calculate some stats values:
for example, correspond to 'a','b','c', I want to aggregate the values (1,4) and (9,8), to get the sum of the 4th and 5th column: (10,12). Get the mean of them: (5,6). How can I realize it ?

Comment: What's the desired output? The easiest would be using data frame API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rdd:

```
(data.map(lambda x: (x[:3], x[3:] + (1,)))
     .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)))
     .map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0]/x[1][2], x[1][1]/x[1][2])))
).collect()

# [(('a', 'b', 'c'), (5, 6)), (('l', 'g', 'z'), (14, 11)), (('s', 'q', 'a'), (9, 8)), (('o', 'u', 'w'), (43, 40))]
```